# How can I send a variable from AngularJS to Java?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to send a variable inside of a JS Controller to my Java server using $http, but I cant get it to work: once I try it out, I cant enter the HTML view in which this JS code is used, so the problem is coming from the JS controller. Here's what I am doing and the code, based on trying to adapt these two resources:

[docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

[angularjs-http-service-ajax-post-code-example](http://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/angularjs-http-service-ajax-post-code-example)

The controller:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('MessageController', MessageController);

MessageController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', 'MessageTemplate', 'JhiLanguageService'];

onFormatChange.$inject = ['$resource', '$http', 'ServerURL']; // should it be vm.onFormatChange.$inject instead? 

function MessageController ($scope, $stateParams, $uibModalInstance, MessageTemplate, JhiLanguageService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.isSaving = false;

    vm.text = 'Activated'; // this is the only variable
                           // im trying to send to Java

    function onSaveSuccess (result) {
        // a console.log
    }

    function onSaveError (error) {
        // a console.log
    }

    // this function gets called from the HTML via ng-change
    vm.onFormatChange = function () {
        vm.text = vm.status ? 'Deactivated' : 'Activated';

        // Sending vm.text (as "format") to the server 
        $http.post(ServerURL + 'api/format/', {
            format: vm.text // should it be format = vm.text?
            }. {withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                }
        }).then(onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
    }
}
```

Comment: What response are you getting from the server?

Comment: The `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header is illegal in POST requests. It needs to be a response from the server.

Comment: In order for a question to be answered, it must specify what exactly is wrong. Stating simply that “it doesn’t work” is not sufficient. Review the question. Does it provide a full description of what the code did? Does it point out the reasons why this result was not correct? Use the edit link at the bottom of the question to provide these details. If it is not known why your code did not work, that suggests the code as not been debugged. Debugging is one of the first steps developers take when their code fails, and is an important skill to learn.

Comment: If I knew exactly what is wrong, why would I ask the question? If that was the case, fixing it wouldn't be an issue. And I specifically wrote "I cant enter the HTML view in which this JS code is used, so the problem is coming from the JS controller." In top of that, I did some questions in the code comments (that got ignored) which would actually help me to debug.